# How to create custom scroll view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am working on an iOS app and I need to create a zodiac sign picker that allows the user to scroll through 12 images of zodiac signs and select one. The images are named after the signs they represent.

The picker should scroll horizontally from left to right, and there should be a golden circle in the center of the scroll view. If an image gets into the golden circle, it should stay there. If it's not in the golden circle, its opacity should be set to 0.5.

I tried to use the picker view, but I failed to achieve the desired effect.

So at the end I need something similar to card choosing. If we swipe a little bit right It should scroll itself to the center of the Golden circle and update what is currently our chosen zodiac sign. If you need more explanation, ask in comments.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using a `page` styled `TabView` with an overlay containing your ring?

Comment: No, how can I do that?

Comment: OMG. Yes, It begins to look similar to what I'm trying to achieve! Thank you, gonna continue this)